# Setting a forked repo's pull request default branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-fork

**Background:** I have a project "original" in a VSTS-hosted git repo and wanted to create a 
similar project, so I forked the repo. I have no intention of merging from the fork to the original repo - they'll be 2 separate projects. The forked repo's master branch policy that requires pull requests, no direct pushes.

Now, whenever I create such a pull request, the default target is not fork>master but original>master. I always manually change it to fork>master, but it's annoying...

**Questions:**

1. How can I set the fork repo so that pull requests default to fork>master 
   branch?
2. How can I convert the forked repo to a "normal" repo, "forgetting" the original repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of git fork repo is contribute to the upstream (original) repo. So **the forked repo and the original repo always has relations between them**.

And if you want to create a new repo (without any relation with the original repo), but with and same code and branches as the original repo, then you should **create an empty git repo and push all the branches from the original repo into the new created repo** instead of forking the original repo.
Detail steps as below:

#### 1.   Create a new git repo in your VSTS project

In VSTS web page, create a new git repo. Detail steps, you can refer the document [create a repo using the web portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/create-new-repo?view=vsts#create-a-repo-using-the-web-portal).

Assume the git repo name is myrepo and the URL is `https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/myrepo`.

#### 2.   Clone and checkout all the branches from the original repo locally

If you have not cloned the original git repo, you can clone the original git repo by:

```
git clone <original git repo URL>
```

Then checkout all the remote branches locally by the command:

```
git checkout <remote branchname>
```

#### 3.   Push all the branches from local original repo to the new created repo

In the local original git repo, add remote for the new created git repo and push all the branches to the new created git repo. Detail commands as below:

```
#In the local original repo
git remote add myrepo https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/myrepo
git push myrepo --all
```

Now all the branches are pushed into the new created git repo and it's separate with the original git repo.

Comment: I understand that's how I *should've* done it in the first place. Now that I already have the forked repo, I suppose my only option would be to clone *it* using this process? I want to avoid this, since it would require me to setup build/etc all over again. I was hoping for some process that would turn the existing forked repo into a standalone repo.

Comment: @Jonathan But there is no way to change the existing forked repo into a standalone repo. And the only option for your situation to delete the forked repo and create a new one instead.

Comment: If the purpose of a fork is to "contribute to the upstream" then why use one. I can do that with a branch. I fork for many reasons. I have two related but necessarily separate code bases. I want to retain history but start my own project. I have long term feature work I wish to accomplish. All of which may require me to PR into the fork's "master" or "develop" branch long before I'm ready to PR into the upstream.

It's reasonable to ask to be able to change the default PR target.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365802/allow-option-of-converting-forks-to-repos.html

Comment: @DubiousPusher: Upvoted you developercommunity idea. Note that the link has a comment by `Forrest Trepte [MSFT]` that says you can import an existing repo into a new blank repo, so I guess that's easier than the commandline outlined in the answer.